# Where should the word “probably” be placed

Tags: word-order

Consider the following sentences:

> 1. I'll move to the south by then probably.
> 2. I'll probably move to the south by then.
> 3. I'll move to the south probably by then.

Which of the three is correct. In my opinion, the third one is wrong. First two are correct with a small difference in their meaning.

First one makes my probability refer to the time when I'll be moving and the second one tells that there is still a chance that I might not move.

Am I correct?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Although normally called an "adverb", *probably* is often used to modify an entire sentence - in which case it normally appears at the beginning (or the end, if it's "parenthetically" added after a comma)...

> a: Probably I'll move to the south by then.
>    b: I'll move to the south by then[,] probably.

---

In other contexts, syntactically it's more like an adjective than an adverb, in that it normally modifies the immediately following term...

> c: I'll move probably to the south by then.
>    d: I'll move to probably the south by then.

Both of these imply that you *will have moved by then* (possibly to the north, but most likely to the south).

---

> e: I'll move to the south probably by then.

Implies that *you will move to the south* (possibly much later, but most likely "by then").

Comment: Perzackly. And *I'll probably move* I think also belongs in your first category.

Comment: @StoneyB: If the word *move* were emphasised (in a context where the alternative / current situation is *commuting* to the south), I think you'd *probably/almost certainly* have to put it there. But with no special emphasis - yes, it probably comes under category #1. It's still effectively modifying the whole sentence, but since the word/phrase *move [to the south]* is by far the most important part of the sentence, it can stand for the entire statement.

Comment: Also - does anybody actually say /prɒbəbli/? I've never heard anything but /prɒbli/ and /prɒli/. (except of course from actors)

Comment: @StoneyB= I split between /prɒbəbli/ and /prɒbli/ and *never* say  /prɒli/ unless for specific effect.

Comment: @Jim,StoneyB: I use all three forms in speech, depending on how quickly/casually/carelessly I'm speaking. I tend to go for *prolly* in casual written forms to save keystrokes, but I must admit I'm a bit ashamed of myself for doing that because it looks so daft. But I have no such misgiving about discarding *both* **b**'s in rapid speech.

Comment: @StoneyB: /prɒbəbli/ is still pretty common in British English (at least amongst the folk that I work with - most of whom aren't actors). I've never heard anyone use /prɒli/, although I've often seen "probably" abbreviated to "prolly" when written. That being said, I didn't think that "lol" was ever spoken out loud until I went to America and found several young people saying it as if it were an ordinary word.

Comment: @Matt: I'm no great shakes at IPA, but I'm hoping /prɒ:bəbli/ might be a valid representation. I'm pretty sure I "draw out" the first vowel if I'm not bothering with either of the **b**'s. Which for me is very likely in rapid speech.

Answer (score 7):

I think

> I'll probably move to the south by then.

is the best phrase. *Probably* being used as an adverb modifying *move*. Then the flow seems normal and easier to understand.

> I (subject) will probably move (action) to the south (where) by then (when).

If the time were specific, you could put (when) at the beginning, for example

> Next week I'll probably move to the south.

but with indefinate *by then* it sounds strange to say it before we know what the topic is, unless its already known from previous context.

> I am finishing my classes next week. By then, I'll probably move to the south.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. I´ll move to the south by then probably.
> 2. I'll probably move to the south by then.
> 3. I'll move to the south probably by then.

According to adverb position, number two seems to be the **most common** position. i.e. before the main verb and after the auxiliary. According to meaning, it *emphasizes the probability* of the action.

Number two and three are referring to what you want to emphasize more. For example, number one is giving priority to I´ll move to the south by then, whereas the third one prioritize I´ll move to the south.  In number one, the *probability is not so important* and in number three, `probably by then` - **`by then`** is remarked with the probability of taking place by then.