# "We maybe have a problem" or "Maybe we have a problem"? Do we put "maybe" before a verb?

Tags: word-usage, word-order

Maybe is an adverb.

Normally, people put "**Maybe**" at the beginning of a sentence.

Ex: **Maybe we have a problem**

My question is:

Do we put "**maybe**" before a verb? Ex: "**We maybe have a problem**" it sounds very strange.

It is very good if your answer includes some referencing source.

Comment: Is your question about why it can't appear there or simply about what we would say instead since we can't say "maybe have."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where should the word “probably” be placed](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4789/where-should-the-word-probably-be-placed) Also [Question about “surely” and “certainly”.](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23198/question-about-surely-and-certainly)

Comment: @Teacher KSHuang: We certainly *can* say things like [*we maybe have*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22we+maybe+have%22) - it's just that idiomatically it's not particularly common in OP's exact context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Maybe** is what's known as an *adverb of certainty* or *adverb of probability* - it's used to show how certain we are about something. Commonly used  adverbs of probability are:

> certainly - definitely - maybe - possibly
>
> clearly - obviously - perhaps - probably

...and the position of the adverb in the sentence [depends on the adverb being used](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position).

In the case of **maybe**, it is most often placed at the beginning of a sentence (more specifically, at the beginning of a clause)

> - **Maybe** *I will be there*.
> - **Maybe** *we’ll go out to eat tonight*.
> - If you are tired, then **maybe** *it is time to go home*.

In certain situations, *maybe* can be placed at the end of a sentence, for example, if we are making a suggestion which we are not very certain about.

> A: My car won't start.
>   B: It could be the battery, **maybe**.

As mentioned in the comments, **maybe** can also be a sentence in itself, for example, if we wish to express uncertainty in response to a suggestion:

> A: Would you like to have chicken curry for dinner?
>
> B: **Maybe**.

...or if we agree that something is possible:

> A: Do you think we can get to the movie theatre before 7:00?
>
> B: **Maybe**.

Looking your two suggested sentences

1. We maybe have a problem.
2. Maybe we have a problem.

...it should take the form of ***maybe [clause]***, therefore

> **Maybe** we have a problem.

...is the better choice.

Answer (score -3):

Short Answer: No, we don't.

Long Answer: Your gut is correct. We would say,

> We **might** have a problem.
>
> We **may** have a problem.
>
> It **may be** that we have a problem. (If you really want to use "may" and "be."

As for a reference link, I simply Googled "[maybe may be](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/maybe-or-may-be)".

And this is a reference link on adverb placement. Scroll down to "[Certainty or obligation](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/about-adjectives-and-adverbs/adverbs-and-adverb-phrases-position)" in the table.

Longer Answer: However, it's not completely uncommon nor wrong in that [people still do it](https://www.google.com.tw/search?q=%22maybe%20have%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr&ei=AbN0WP7tKYSi8QWuzLaoCg), so perhaps the rule is not a hard and fast one.

What do you think? Do the example ones of "maybe have" sound weird to you?

Comment: Hmm... what do think about these examples? https://www.google.com/search?q="we+maybe+have"&tbm=bks

Comment: @DamkerngT. Heh, thanks. I had actually been interrupted in the middle of including similar examples in my answer.

Comment: We maybe will find that rules describing adverb placement are a bit more complicated.

Comment: A key is that *maybe* can modify an entire sentence, or certain parts of a sentence.

Comment: Or even be a sentence. Maybe.

Comment: @Jim: *Or [even be maybe a](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22even+be+maybe+a%22) sentence*.

Comment: @Fum *Houston, maybe we be a problem.*